# Generalized Likelihood Ratio for variance in Normal Hierarchical Models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio

We have a Linear Hierarchical Model where

$$Y_i | \theta_i \sim N(\theta_i,1)$$

$$\theta_i | A \sim N(0,A)$$

with

$$Y_i |A \sim N(0,A+1)$$

where $ i = 1,2,\ldots,k.$

I found the likelihood function for $A$ by using the marginal distribution of the $Y_i$'s, where

$$L(A+1) = \prod_{i=1}^k f_{Y_i}(y_i | A+1)$$
$$ = [2\pi(A+1)]^\frac{-k}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2(A+1)}\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2}I(A \geq 0) $$

From this, I found the MLE for $A$, which is
$$\hat{A} = \max \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2}{k}, 0 \right) $$
where $A \geq 0$, because it's variance.

However, I do not know how to proceed with a generalized likelihood ratio to find the test statistic. I don't want to use a large sample approximation by taking the log to get a chi squared distribution. Apparently the Generalized likelihood ratio is supposed to evaluate to a known distribution. I want to test the hypothesis that
$$H_0: A = 0$$
$$H_1: A > 0$$

and I'm not sure how to proceed.